# How to read jsp form data and enter it into Mongodb database using servlet

Tags: jsp, mongodb, servlets

I have created a servlet named as FirstClass and following is my web.xml

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>FirstClass</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.app.FirstClass</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>FirstClass</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/db</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

When in url pattern if i write /db.jsp and run tomcat a blank page appears while in console message appears The stack name is : null and the value got inserted to Database.
Here is my  Servlet Class .

```
public class FirstClass extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest Request , HttpServletResponse Response)throws ServletException,IOException{

        String stack = Request.getParameter("do_it");
        System.out.println("The stack name is : " + stack);


        try{    

            Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost" , 27017);

            DB db = mongo.getDB("newdb");

            DBCollection table = db.getCollection("user");

            BasicDBObject obj = new BasicDBObject();
            obj.put("name", employee);


            table.insert(obj);

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution , it was happening because  needs to be matched with  and that I was doing wrong as I was calling some jsp .